# Generating a set using higher order functions and unions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am studying a past exam and I came across a question where I must write a function called setFunc to generate a set where I apply a function on each element in a list of tuples (which are a result of the Cartesian product operation)

First I implemented a helper function to take the union of sets:

Then I tried to implement the main function:

```
setFunc x y = f x y
setFunc (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) OrdUnion (setFunc f xt ys)
```

Help on fixing setFunc would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to implement the function setFunc

Comment: This is almost identical to the original version of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877146/cartesian-product-set-generation), before you edited it to say something entirely different. The only difference is your destructuring of the Cartesian product into some union of sets, the right-hand side of which makes absolutely no mathematical sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product set generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877146/cartesian-product-set-generation)

Comment: And just to emphasize what the comments on *that* question said: the thing you are looking for is called a Cartesian product. Not a union. A union does not help you here. At all. There is no union-like operation that can take two sets of three elements each and get a set of nine elements. That's a Cartesian product.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that did not answer my question because the function did not match the function signature of setFunc above. Also that solution used sorting, which is forbidden for this question. I think ordUnion could help since the input lists are sorted and the output list also must be sorted.

Comment: The type signature makes no sense without context. What are we supposed to use the Ord for?

Comment: It's for indicating that the input lists and the output list are ordered (sorted in ascending order)

Comment: If your policy is to represent sets by ordered lists, it might be worth stating so explicitly; please note that incurs the risk of getting *quadratic algorithms*. Do you need something equivalent to: `setFunc f xs ys = sort $ do { x <- xs ; y <- ys ; return (f x y) }`  ?

Comment: @jpmarinier yes, but I must use ordUnion somehow and I am not permitted to use sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > I must use `ordUnion` somehow and I am not permitted to use `sort`.

This sort of constraint is expected to appear within the *body* of the question.

A core part of the problem is that we want the output list to be *sorted* (from your example), but we are told *nothing* about possible order-preserving properties of the argument function. So we must accept that the `f x y` output values will be produced in some unpredictable random order.

For example, we expect this equality to hold:

```
setFunc (*) [-7,2] [-7,3] == [-21,-14,6,49]
```

that is, the maximal output value results from the two *minimal* input values.

Hence, we are somewhat coerced into solving the problem in 2 steps:

1. produce the `f x y` output values in whatever order
2. sort the list produced in step 1.

Let's call the step 1 function `cartesianFunc`. It is easy to write it in recursive fashion:

```
cartesianFunc :: Ord c => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
cartesianFunc f   []   ys  =  []
cartesianFunc f (x:xs) ys  =  (map (f x) ys)  ++  (cartesianFunc f xs ys)
```

Note that we have dropped the useless `Ord` constraints on types b and c.

**Testing:**

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
 λ> 
 λ> :load q13784671.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q13784671.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> cartesianFunc (*) [1,2,4] [1,3,9]
 [1,3,9,2,6,18,4,12,36]
 λ>
```

**Now for step 2:**

We may not use the library `sort` function. But we have to use function `ordUnion`, which merges two ordered lists into a bigger ordered list.

Assuming we had yet another function, say `splitHalf`, which could split a list into two roughly equal parts, we could obtain our own sort function by:

1. splitting the input list
2. *recursively* sorting its two halves
3. combining our two sorted halves using the merging `ordUnion` function.

To split a list, we can use the well-know [*tortoise-hare algorithm*](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2019-05-08-list-manipulation-tricks.html) where at each iteration, the first part advances by one step and the second part advances by two steps.

This gives this code:

```
ordUnion :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
ordUnion a      []     = a
ordUnion []     b      = b
ordUnion (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of
    LT -> x : ordUnion xs  (y:ys)
    EQ -> x : ordUnion xs     ys
    GT -> y : ordUnion (x:xs) ys


splitHalfTH :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitHalfTH xs = th xs xs
  where
    th (y:ys)  (_:_:zs)  =  let  (as,bs) = th ys zs  in  (y:as, bs)
    th ys _              =  ([],ys)


mySort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mySort  []   =  []
mySort  [a]  =  [a]
mySort  xs   =  let  (as,bs) = splitHalfTH xs  in  ordUnion (mySort as) (mySort bs)
```

and finally we can come up with our `setFunc` function by combining `mySort` and `cartesianFunc`:

```
setFunc :: Ord c => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
setFunc fn xs ys = mySort (cartesianFunc fn xs ys)
```

**Testing**:

```
 λ> 
 λ> cartesianFunc (*) [1,2,4] [1,3,9]
 [1,3,9,2,6,18,4,12,36]
 λ> 
 λ> mySort $ cartesianFunc (*) [1,2,4] [1,3,9]
 [1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36]
 λ> 
 λ> setFunc  (*) [1,2,4] [1,3,9]
 [1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36]
 λ>
```